# Wrong hostname in squash TM on external server

Tags: java, squash, server-name

I have a problem with reporting bug in squash TM. This is problem connected with my server name on which squash is installed. I have it on external server. In one place in application I got wrong URL like this:

```
http://localhost:8040/squash/executions/49/info
```

and it should be:

```
http://**my_server**/squash/executions/49/info
```

in stderrout.log file generated by squash I found error:

```
org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ServerNameMatcher DEBUG: looking for hostname match on current server name localhost
```

How to change the name of this server to proper name, not 'localhost'. I'm looking in every config file of squash but cannot find. Any ideas?

EDIT: I have to admit, that when I installed squash on localhost, everything is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If this only happens at a particular place, it may be a bug. I suggest you to post your question to [Squash TM forums](http://www.squashtest.org/index.php/en/support-99807/forum-squash).